# For this drawing, is the front side view for this object supposed to be sectioned out or do you use only hidden lines instead?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

For this drawing, is the front side view for this object supposed to be sectioned out or do you use only hidden lines instead ?

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't asked you for a section view. It clearly *has* asked you for a left side view which means the view from outside the object.

There is no requirement in the question to show hidden lines but it would be normal to include them for clarity to show the depth of each hole - through holes in this case.

Comment: what is meant by 1.000 REAM ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reamer#:~:text=A%20reamer%20is%20a%20type,accuracy%20to%20leave%20smooth%20sides.&text=The%20process%20of%20enlarging%20the%20hole%20is%20called%20reaming. Post your drawing when you've finished and we'll check it out.

Comment: @Kauri I believe it means a 1” hole reamed to size.

Answer (score 0):

The front view differs from a section view. As the section view will see solid lines representing the edges of the holes at the cut; the lines are dashed in the front view to indicate the depth of the bores.

Comment: what is meant by 1.000 REAM ?

Comment: Remove by making a hole or by boring.